# Switch Statement and Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, switch-statement

If i get the user to input a value in String from the menu output on the screen. How can i use that input for a switch statement? it keeps it can be only used for int.
For example, if a user enters a, i want it to switch to the case statement and do the actions. Sorry if this is confusing.

```
public static void sortData(short days[], String name[]) {
    String choice;
    Scanner kd = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("a. Sort by Name\nb. Sort by Day");
    choice = kd.next();                       // ????????

    switch (choice) {
    case 1: {                                // ?????????
```

Comment: Can't you just get the first character of the string and use that instead of a String? As far as I know you _can_ use chars for a switch.

Comment: @11684 i tried using char, it would compile without any errors but when i entered input, it woudnt display anything. hence i changed it to String.

Comment: Are you using Java 7 ? You can use String in cases then !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is okay:

```
public static void sortData(short days[], String name[]) {
    char choice;
    Scanner kd = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("a. Sort by Name\nb. Sort by Day");
    choice = kd.next().toCharArray()[0];

    switch (choice) {
    case 'a':
        // do something
        break;
    case 'b';
        // do something else
        break;
    }
}
```

**Not tested**

Comment: i got it working from your suggestion. found my mistake. thanks for your input @11684

Answer (score 3):

You could define a list of strings for your accepted choices and use `indexOf` to find the entered input. After that you can use the index in your `switch`.

Like this

```
List<String> options = Arrays.asList("name", "day", "color", "smell");
switch (options.indexOf(choice)) {
case 0: // name
    ...
case 1: // day
    ...
... // etc
default: // none of them
}
```

However, using the numbers is not very readable.

Another idea: define an enum and use `valueOf(choice)`. In this case you have to catch an `IllegalArgumentException` for non matching inputs.

```
enum Options {
    name, day, color, smell
}
```

and then

```
try {
    switch (Options.valueOf(choice)) {
    case name: ...
    case day: ...
    // etc
    }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // none of them
}
```

or, finally, you switch to Java 7 ;-)

Comment: we havnt been taught indexOf as of yet. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Great answer, a lot better than mine. The trick with the list is great!